# Arrays.asList(array) in java add unwanted spaces between comma separated string?

Tags: java

I have a string array that I convert to ArrayList and remove an item from it. Then use that updated ArrayList.

**Problem**
Initial Input:

```
String[] arr = {"467","470","464","410"};
List<String> idList = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(arr));
```

After converting and removing item it prints

```
[467, 470, 464]
```

It adds unwanted leading white spaces between the elements of list, which causes trouble as then I operate on it using

```
if (idList.toString().contains(userId)) {
      idList.remove(userId); 
}
```

So if userId="470" and in this list it is " 470", it doesn't match due to white space's issue and code fails.

It tried few things like `using integer array instead of string`, but it makes no difference.

or

```
List<String> idList = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(arr));
System.out.println("==>"+idList);

List afterRemovingWhiteSpace = new ArrayList<>();
idList.forEach(e -> afterRemovingWhiteSpace.add(e.trim()));
System.out.println("Updated==>"+afterRemovingWhiteSpace);
```

or

```
String[] arr = {"467", "470", "464"};
List<String> idList = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(arr));
System.out.println("==>"+idList);
String regex = "^\\s+";
idList.forEach(e -> e.replaceAll(regex, ""));
System.out.println("Updated==>"+idList);
```

But none works. Any idea how to do it efficiently, I don't want use array and remove an item from it, as list can contain large number of elements and that will become very costly operation.

Comment: This is not ArrayList it is LinkedList

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This worked, by combining @matt answer's

```
List<String> idList = new LinkedList<>();
    idList.add("1");
    idList.add("          2");
    String userId = "2";
    List<String> removeLeadingWhiteSpacesList = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println("idList=>"+idList);
    for (String temp : idList) {
        removeLeadingWhiteSpacesList.add(temp.trim());
    }
    if (removeLeadingWhiteSpacesList.contains(userId)) {
        removeLeadingWhiteSpacesList.remove(userId);
        System.out.println("removeLeadingWhiteSpacesList=>"+removeLeadingWhiteSpacesList);
    }
```

It outputs

```
idList=>[1,           2]
removeLeadingWhiteSpacesList=>[1]
```

Comment: As in my other comment, try `idList.add(" 123"); String userId = "12"; if (idList.stream().collect( Collectors.joining(",")).contains(userId)) { System.out.println("It failed"); } `.

Comment: Yup!, basically I have to trim the values and store it in other List and use that list. But this is what I did not wanted to do, as list is going to contain very large number of elements and it is not an optimized solution. Anyways Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: No, what you have to do is listen to the people here and check the list's content rather than analyzing a stringified version.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the `contains` method on the `LinkedList`

```
if (idList.contains(userId)) {
```

see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#contains(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm missing something, instead of

```
if (idList.toString().contains(userId)) {
```

use [`List.contains(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-)

```
if (idList.contains(userId)) {
```

Comment: List<String> idList = new LinkedList<>();
        idList.add("1");
        idList.add("  2");
        String userId = "2";
        if (idList.contains(userId)) {
            System.out.println("It Worked");
        }

Comment: @Sam Why did you add a space when you added `2` to `idList`? `List<String> idList = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(arr));` does not do that. Also, if you only store `int` values, using a `List<Integer> idList` would make more sense. Since `Integer` can never contain a space.

Comment: I have string values and idList.add(" 2"), this is what I am getting after calling an API, cannot change it.

Comment: Then `trim()` the values. Or `trim()` and convert to `int`. And that's not a great result from calling an API.

Comment: @Sam listen to Elliot. Otherwise `idList.add(" 123"); String userId = "12"; if (idList.toString().contains(userId)) { System.out.println("It failed"); } `

Answer (score 0):

You're printing out a list, the default toString will add spaces between elements.

```
System.out.println("[" + idList.stream().collect( Collectors.joining(",")) + "]");
```

That will concatenate the list without spaces.

This:

```
System.out.println("==>"+idList);
```

Adds spaces to the printed string only, not the elements of the list. So do both of these.

```
System.out.println("Updated==>"+afterRemovingWhiteSpace);
System.out.println("Updated==>"+idList);
```

*The elements of the list were not changed*

Another misconception you seem to be having.

```
"[123, 456]".contains("456");
"[123,456]".contains("456");
```

Both strings will contain 456, the spaces won't change that.

Comment: Also `"[123, 1456]".contains("456");` is also true

Answer (score 0):

You can trim spaces using this:

```
List<String> newList = new LinkedList<String>();
for(String x: idList)
        newList.add(x.trim());
```